# How do I use a distribution like an equation?

Tags: statistics

I have a right-skewed distribution that contains the head-body lengths of 1500 mammals and managed to transform it into a "satisfactory" normal model.

**I was wondering if there was a way to create an equation using these two distributions, such that when I input a new length, it outputs a new value based on the normal model.**

---

Originally the question was how to turn a right-skewed distribution into a normal model, but I realized I could use an inverse log to create one.

Here is the explanation of what I did
I am trying to make a fable, but I would like to keep the characters/animals to be relatively the same height compared to each other. However, I still want their height differences to be fairly consistent (E.g. a mouse is not taller than a rabbit).

I tried making a system to help me with this, but I am having a lot of trouble creating it.

So I took all the animals that had a head-body length measurement from the database and put them into excel. I then took out any order that had aquatic animals in it, taking care of our chunky whales.

I thought that once I removed the largest animals on the planet, that I would end up with a nice normal distribution. I then created a histogram and saw that it was heavily skewed right and attempted to normalize it with an inverse log function. I ended up with a sort-of normal model.

**I used this database to get all the head-body lengths of all mammals in the database:**
http://esapubs.org/archive/ecol/E090/184/PanTHERIA_1-0_WR05_Aug2008.txt

**Excel Containing the Data:**
https://1drv.ms/x/s!Ai_-tIyVvFU8hU6Y7Ee7U_paZHCF

**This post got messed up as I didn't exactly know what I was asking, as well as figuring it out later on.**

Comment: I'm afraid it is not clear what you mean by "compressing the values"

Comment: I editted the question and description?

Comment: I want it such that an animal that is very large gets downsized significantly, while a very small animal gets upsized significantly. However, still want to sort of maintain a normal distribution as close as possible.

Comment: It amy be best to describe what you want with a numerical example.

Comment: I changed it again, hope this explains my question better :P sorry about that

Comment: Why do you want to force a distribution to be something it isn't?

Comment: I am trying to create a fable and I decided that I would like to keep their heights relatively the same, but I want their differences in height to be consistent using a system instead of eyeballing it.